Gnome Tweaks Not working in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I’m using Ubuntu 24.04 and would like to install Gnome Tweaks to change start up sounds. Everything I’ve heard about installing Gnome Tweaks in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is that it does NOT work and is broken, so I haven't installed it yet. My research shows no fix.
By confirming the “universe repository” is enabled on your system, will that alone fix Gnome Tweaks in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS if installed? If NOT what needs to be done so it works in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?
I am new to Linux, so would need detailed steps showing how this could be fixed. Thank you.

I haven't tried Gnome Tweaks myself, but from some research:

The Ask Ubuntu question Gnome tweak tool crashes ubuntu 24.04LTS with Gnome v46 reports:

Gnome tweak tool causes "Oh no! something went wrong" message. Rebooting system etc wont fix the issue!
This happen when I: Run tweak tool > select Appearance > change Cursor from Yaru to something else.


The above question references Bug #2062377 Ubuntu 24.04: gnome-shell crashes on Xorg if a legacy X11 cursor theme is selected
Bug #2062377 has comment #30 from July 2024:

This bug was fixed in the package mutter - 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.1


On a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS installation dpkg -l mutter reports version 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.2 is installed. I.e. the fix for bug #2062377 has been made published.


If this bug was fixed in the package mutter - 46.2-1ubuntu0.24.04.1 as stated above, what would be the exact command line needed to apply the fix?  Remember I am a newbie.
